# Border around a centered div

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to put a border / shadow around each of my separated 'blocks' of my forum. I'm using the IPS Community forum software with the Blue Lagoon theme.

I've seperated the blocks with padding and then tried to put a border on it however obviously it spans the width of the screen and isn't tight around the slideshow 'block'. I don't know how things are centred as I'm effectively just editing a template that is extremely user unfriendly.

```
.block-split {
   padding-top: 8px;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
   border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Is my css for splitting up the blocks and the border.

*Basically, how do I get a border / shadow around the specific elements that doesn't span the width of the screen*

Below should be a picture of the problem

Thanks =]

*Link to the site can be provided if requested*
[image]

Comment: did you try margin for separate the div and make the border for it.??

Comment: A link to the site is needed to check the HTML structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to select a child of your chosen element an put the border around that. I guess your chosen element is not the one you wanted to put the border around.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, or atleast would require going through a fair few poorly named files. I'm editing this from a 'globalTemplate' where everything is added either via php or hard coded on, which this whole block seems to be done via php: http://prntscr.com/g89974

Comment: you can do something like
```.border > *```
to select the direct child

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.. 
Copied the css it was using into a different class, re-assigned what class the slideshow was using and added the border ^_^